# Como desarmo listas dentro de otras listas?

Tags: python, lista, scraping

Estoy intentando scrapear varios precios de una página y obtengo esto como resultado:

> [['[$573.81]'], ['[$124.52'], ['[$284.86]'], ['[$393.96]'], ['[]']]

Ya probé varias cosas, replace, remove, convertirlo a str, y no encuentro la manera.

Alguna idea?

El código es:

```
def scrapeo (lista):
  precios = []
  for i in lista:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.get(i)
    #Incorporo BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    #Extraigo la pagina principal y convierto a str
    pagina_principal_bs4 = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-sm-5 col-xs-7 precio'})
    pagina=str(pagina_principal_bs4)
    pagina = " ".join(pagina.split())
##    print(pagina)
    def cleanhtml(pagina): 
      cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
      cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '\n', pagina)
      return cleantext
    texto= cleanhtml(pagina).replace("\n", "").split(",")
##    print(texto)
    precio = texto[0].split(" ")
    precios.append(precio)
  return(precios)

#-----------Descartables--------------------
data = pd.read_excel (r'path', sheet_name='Salud')
subset = data[data.Fuente == "Analgésicos"]
links= subset.loc [:, 'link']

descartables=[]
for i in links:
  descartables.append(i)
  
precios_descartables = str(scrapeo(descartables))
print(precios_descartables)
precios_descartables = [s.replace('$', '') for s in precios_descartables]
```

Comment: en la segunda lista parece que te falta cerrar un corchete, por favor verifica, si te falta cerraar entonces todo se vuelve facil, de lo contrario se podría complicar un poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla sería recorrer la lista e ir quitando los caracteres que no nos interesa. Una forma puede ser así:

```py
lista = [['[$573.81]'], ['[$124.52'], ['[$284.86]'], ['[$393.96]'], ['[]']]

for element in lista:
  i = lista.index(element)
  lista[i] = element[0].replace("$","").replace("[","").replace("]","")
print(lista)

#otra forma
lista = [element[0].replace("$","").replace("[","").replace("]","") for element in lista]
print(lista)
```

Tamién podrías usar el módulo `ast` para convertir cada string a una lista y luego ya qutiar algunas cosas. O podrías usar expresiones regulares

Comment: Perfecto, con eso y no convertir el resultado de la función en str me funcionó! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa asumiendo que todos los elementos siempre estarán delimitados por `[` y por `]` y que solo hay un precio por cada elemento en la lista (no se presentan casos como `[['[$10.00, $20.00]']]`), sería usar una expresión regular para encontrar aquello que esté dentro de ambos carácteres, la cual es: `\[(.*?)\]`.

Después tienes que obtener el primer grupo de captura para obtener el valor que está delimitado. Si quieres hacer la asignación sobre la misma lista entonces puedes usar [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para obtener el índice y hacer la asignación sobre la misma posición.

```py
import re

lista = [['[$573.81]'], ['[$124.52]'], ['[$284.86]'], ['[$393.96]'], ['[]']]
delimitador = "\[(.*?)\]"
regex = re.compile(delimitador)

for i, elemento in enumerate(lista):
    lista[i] = re.match(regex, elemento[0]).groups()[0]

print(lista)
# Salida:
# ['$573.81', '$124.52', '$284.86', '$393.96', '']
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud) de la regex.